# How can I prevent org-mode reading agenda files when started?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

My org-mode agenda files are on a remote machine, accessed via ssh using tramp.  When org-mode starts it *always* reads this file, which is inconvenient as it makes opening any org file very slow.  I would prefer for it to read the agenda files only when I actually look at the agenda.  Is there a way to do this?

My `.emacs` currently sets the agenda location in this way:

```
  (setq org-agenda-files '("/-:somehost:somefile.org"))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could have a generic local location for org-files on the host computer (which can be an empty directory or a directory with no org-files at all) and then modify the value for `org-agenda-files` when you do whatever it is that is meant to query off-site files.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  The org-files that I need to see the agenda from could set `org-agenda-files`.  Yes!

Comment: If just loading org-mode causes Emacs to try and read your agenda file and hence open a Tramp connection, then I'd recommend you report it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  It's normal that it fetches the file when you want to view your agenda, but not when you're looking at some unrelated org-mode file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `use-package`, treat org-agenda as separate package, defer its loading and declare `org-agenda-files` there. It should load the variable just before the agenda is loaded.

Alternatively I guess that you can exclude that file from your init file, and use `add-to-list` in `org-agenda-mode-hook`or any other convenient place you'll call before loading agenda-mode. This way will allow you to set conditional statements conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on was to remove the setting for `org-agenda-files` from my `.emacs` and instead to set `org-agenda-files` within some [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) in the org-mode files that were actually relevant to the agenda. i.e. a block of code like this at the end of those files:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq org-agenda-files '("/-:somehost:somefile.org"))
# End:
```

Comment: Interesting, so you would load the local file, say ~/work-agenda which would then load the org agenda file when you call upon org-agenda?